# Hiking trails between Mt Moosilauke and Rumney NH

Tags: trails, new-england

I would like to hike from [Mt Moosilauke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Moosilauke) to [Rumney NH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumney,_New_Hampshire). From the [all trials map](https://www.alltrails.com/explore/us/new-hampshire/rumney) it looks like I can take the *Carriage Road Trail* almost all the way to some sort of extension to the *Three Ponds Trail*, but it does not look like there is an easy way to connect the last half mile from *Breezy Point Rd* to what I am hoping is a trailhead. Then from the southern trailhead it looks like I would have to walk 6 miles on Stinson Lake Rd to get to Rumney.

Is it possible to connect the Carriage Road Trail and the Three Ponds Trail?
Can I avoid the road walk on Stinson Lake Rd?
Is there a better route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see on USGS Topo maps and aerial imagery, you definitely need to walk on Breezy Pt Rd and NH118 to cross Baker River before getting on Three Ponds trail. Can't see any apparent crossing/bridge anywhere else.

As for a trail from Stinson Lake south to Rumney, I can't find any reference anywhere about that. I took a look at [this parcel data](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=066a3f90953f4a01a941e2cefa883ae1) and it seems there might be a lot of privately owned land all along that corridor. Lots and lots of small parcels.

That might be why no north-south trail crosses that area. If Rumney as a terminus can't be changed, I'm afraid walking Stinson Lake road might be the only option. Unless you have nothing against bushwhacking - but inflicting yourself 6 miles of that would be uselessly masochistic.